# IdentityServer4 direct interactions via UI mobile app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, identityserver4

I'm creating a centralized authentication system for multiple mobile applications. Its architecture is based on the OpenID Connect flow through the use of OAuth2.0 with IdentityServer4 on ASP.NET Core Identity.

I have researched a lot and in the main implementations with the Authorization Code Flow observed there is always the redirection of the user from the mobile app UI to the server web views, to allow the management of its profile.

This is very uncomfortable, because it significantly compromises the UX. I would like the user to be able to register and authenticate himself directly from the app interface without any redirection that involves opening a browser. Is there a way to do this with only API calls, from the client backend to the centralized authorization server?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Resource Owner Password Credentials` grant type where you can pass the user credentials to the token endpoint and receive an [access token](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/aspnetcore2/topics/grant_types.html#resource-owner-password). But usage of the ROPC grant type is highly discouraged as you can read in this [blog post](https://www.scottbrady91.com/OAuth/Why-the-Resource-Owner-Password-Credentials-Grant-Type-is-not-Authentication-nor-Suitable-for-Modern-Applications) from Scott Brady, one of the creators of Identity Server.

What I can propose to you is to use `Authorization Code` flow to login the user and get access token for them, and then creating your custom API endpoints on identity server for user management. More on custom api endpoints [here](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/add_apis.html)

Comment: Yes, the authorization code flow is what I chose. I don't understand this part: "use Authorization Code flow to login the user", how can I avoid using the web browser to login?

Comment: Well with auth code you cant avoid the browser, even on desktop, when you login visual studio account forbexample, it uses browser. So to summarize, if u dont want the browser your option is to use ROPC, with anything else you must use the browser...